# How to get rid off indentation and how can i tell Simple xml framework, not to convert " to &quot; while serializing object

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am using Simple framework to serialize an annotated object to xml. Everything works fine, except that framework while serializing converts all occurance of `"` to `&quot;`

How can I avoid this ?

Also how can i get rid of the indentations ?

Comment: Can you post a small example?

Comment: For instance xml <so>vd:"9368"</so> will be converted to  <os>vd:&quot;9368&quot;</os>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't xml meant to do so? I don't know any option to disable this. But as a workaround you may implement a [`Transform`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html), which (un-)escapes your quoutes.

Edit: Possible the `org.simpleframework.xml.stream.Formatter` class can help you. This will escape those sequences. But not sure if you can customize it per code or you have to work on source-level.

---

**Disable indention:**

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new Format(0));
```

Will set indention count to 0.

Please see [`Format`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/stream/Format.html).

Comment: yeah but there are some exceptional cases where we require " to be used in xml!

Comment: I see ... just checked out `Transformer`; doesn't help here because the replacing is done after the transformer.

Comment: ollo, Ok... I have one more question do you know how to rip off indentation , new line etc during serialization with simple framework ?

Comment: Please see also my comment according to `Formatter` class.